# How to place a text area in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, jtextarea

I have created a `JFrame` containing 2 `JPanels(panel1,panel2)`. I have added `panel2` in `panel1`. `panel1.add(panel2);`

I have added a text area into panel2.

```
panel2.add(textarea);
```

finally `panel1` to `getContentPane`

```
getContentPane().add(panel1);
```

Now I am getting the location of textarea by

```
textarea.getLocation();
```

I have created a Save button which saves the `textarea(x,y)` values. I am using xml to store (x,y) values.

Now when I close and reopen the jar file the textarea place is not changed but the xml values are showing the changed textarea location values .

How to solve?

Comment: When it's you, and not the variable `i`, please write `I` next time :)

Comment: The text area us likely under the control of a layout manager.  You're going to have to provide a runnable example of your problem before we can move beyond simple guessing

Comment: maybe call a validate() and repaint() on the frame to update the rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do filing; put x and y  values to some variables.
Then put it on JTextArea textArea by ::

```
textArea.setText(arg);
```